# PHP Try/Catch block halting code execution

Tags: php

I'm running the following code:

```
    try {

        $count = $user[0]->followers_count;

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return 'error';
    }

    dd('continuing execution');
```

Which outputs this:

> FatalErrorException in Twitter.php line 174: Cannot use object of type
>   stdClass as array

Now, a quote from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955721/2724978

> First of all one should make clear that an exception is only fatal if
>   it is not caught. Catching an exception does not halt script
>   execution.

My code is not continuing the execution even though it's on a try/catch block. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, what is it?

Comment: You are returning in the catch that will stop the script.

Comment: I have to assume `$user` is an object and not an array so try `$count = $user->followers_count;`

Comment: it would output 'error' then.. I commented that line, still same output.

Comment: it returns from an external API in multiple formats, I'm not trying to debug this, I'm trying to keep it running in spite of possible bugs.

Comment: Ok Is any of these lines line 174 of `Twitter.php`

Comment: $count = $user[0]->followers_count; is line 174.. it does raise an exception, depending on the result I get from the API

Comment: it can be any exception.. $ds = 100/0; will return division by 0 instead of "continuing execution"

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer I found is that in PHP, Errors and Exceptions are different things.. Exceptions can be caught and code will not halt. Errors such as FatalErrorException, on the other hand, will always halt the application even if it's in a try/catch block.

No way around it, have to write code for checking variable types.

Also, another thing.. Sometimes (in laravel for example) you gotta use \Exception instead of just Exception.

Comment: Take a look on the example on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

About the \Exception needed in some files, those are instances where your code declared a different namespace (keyword use), as in this:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

If no namespace was declared, then you don't need the trailing \ before builtin class names.