# Showing failed wp_remote_post on user registration

Tags: php, wordpress, exception

When registering user, I am hooking into `user_register` hook to send some call to the external API.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'create_user_on_api' );
```

inside the `create_user_on_api` function I am making the call (nonces are there, and tons of security checks, but I'm omitting those for brevity) using `wp_remote_post()`

```
function create_user_on_api( $user_id ) {
    $user_create_response = wp_remote_post( "someurlgoeshere.api", $curl_args );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user_create_response ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'wp error' );
    } else {
        $code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $user_create_response );
        $msg = wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $user_create_response );
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $user_create_response );

        if ( $code !== 200 ) {
            throw new Exceprion( 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the gist of it.

The problem is following: using any error handles causes white screen of death, error is logged in my debug.log, and I would like to throw a notice on my admin dashboard that, even though api call failed, the user is created in WP, and you'll have to create it manually on the API or try again.

I tried echoing stuff, custom exception handling mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955436/resume-php-to-execution-script-after-exception), but so far no luck.

Any idea how to do that? Can I hook into admin notices in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution. A hacky one but it works.

On api error I am storing a error message in a transient, which has an expiry of 60 seconds and I created a `user_notices` function that I hook on `admin_notices` hook. In it I check two things: if I'm on users screen

```
$current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $current_screen->id === 'users' ) {
    }
```

And then inside this I check if the transients are empty, and then assign them to the `$error_message` array, which I output in a `foreach` (in case I have multiple error messages)

```
  if ( ! empty( $error_msg_array ) ) {
    foreach ( $error_msg_array as $error_msg_key => $error_msg ) {
    ?>
    <div class="error notice">
        <p><?php printf( '<strong>Apigee error:</strong> %s', esc_html( $error_msg ) ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
  }
```

And this seems to be working.